# Mongoose find() returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having issues with trying to get my data down from the monogodb free edition. I have an app called the `travel-app` and a collection called `Trips`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tripEventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    startdate: Date,
    enddate: Date,
    cost: String,
    tripevent: String
  });
  
  const tripSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    startdate: Date,
    enddate: Date,
    tripevents: [tripEventSchema]
  });
  
    const Trip = mongoose.model('Trips', tripSchema);

module.exports = Trip;
```

my routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const Trip = require('../models/event'); // Update the path based on your directory structure

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const events = await Trip.find({});
      console.log('Events:', events); // Add this line
      res.json(events);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error:', err); // Add this line
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  });


module.exports = router;
```

and my server without the username or password

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const eventsRouter = require('./routes/events');

const app = express();

const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://:@travel-app.jdkjive.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to the database');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
  });

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/events', eventsRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Whenever I route to localhost:3000/events it returns a [] but i definitely have data in my collect - directly copied from the collection e.g

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"64d904b9492a3c552b44f4d4"},"name":"Example Event","description":"This is an example event description.","startdate":"2023-08-15","enddate":"2023-08-18","tripevents":[{"name":"Trip 1","description":"This is the description of Trip 1.","tripevent":"Type A","startdate":"2023-08-15","enddate":"2023-08-16","cost":{"$numberInt":"500"}},{"name":"Trip 2","description":"This is the description of Trip 2.","tripevent":"Type B","startdate":"2023-08-17","enddate":"2023-08-18","cost":{"$numberInt":"750"}}]}
```

[image: mongodb collection]

Comment: check out your incorrect path in the require statement for the Trip model in your routes file. You need to update the path to match the correct location of your model file.

If that is the right path then you need to make sure that the collection name in the mongoose.model call matches the actual collection name in the MongoDB database

Comment: i tried that, that';s not the issue unfortunately

Comment: does your collection name in the mongoose.model call match the collection name in your mongo db?

Comment: @QueryKiller see updated post, i uploaded a screenshot of my db

Comment: I can see in the dashboard that connections are being made and requests just the data isn't coming back for some reason

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling):

> Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database.

Your collection is named `Trips` in mongodb. You need to name it `trips`.

Also change this:

```
const Trip = mongoose.model('Trips', tripSchema);
```

to this:

```
const Trip = mongoose.model('Trip', tripSchema);
```